# Instance Show for specific data

Tags: string, haskell, instance, show

I have defined the following type:

```
   data Taula = Taula String [[String]]
```

And I created the following instance:

```
instance Show Taula   
   where 
     show  Taula [( n , i , c )]  = show  Taula [( n , i , c )]++ "\n" 
     show ( l : ls )  = show l ++  "\n"  ++ show ls
```

but it generates the following error:

```
  Equations for `show' have different numbers of arguments
  lastHaskell.hs:184:18-82
  lastHaskell.hs:185:18-63
  In the instance declaration for `Show Taula'
```

then try to divide the problem into the following different methods:

```
  instance Show mostrarTaula where
      show (Taula sep []) = ""
      show (Taula sep (k:lls) ) =  show ([tractar sep k]) ++ "\n" 
                                 ++ show (mostrarTaula (Taula sep lls))

--["Hola","Que","fas"] --> "HolakkQuekkfas"
 tractar :: String -> [String] -> String
 tractar sep [] = ""
 tractar sep par = (head par) ++ sep ++ tractar sep (drop 1 par) 

  mostrarTaula :: Taula -> [String] --[[String]] = lls i k=[String]
  mostrarTaula (Taula sep []) = [""]
 mostrarTaula (Taula sep (k:lls) ) =  [tractar sep k] ++ (mostrarTaula(Taula sep lls))
```

As I can do? What I try is to print a data type consisting of [(String, String, String)]? I would like to display the data in tabular form. with \ n after each tuple.

Output example:

`first element tuple1      Second element tuple1     third element tuple1
    first element tuple2      Second element tuple2     third element tuple2
    first element tuple3      Second element tuple3     third element tuple3`

Comment: `monstrarTaula` is *not* a type; it's a function. Only types can belong to typeclasses.

Comment: Okey but generate this error:  
 'lastHaskell.hs:10:48:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Show Taula -- Defined at lastHaskell.hs:10:48
      instance Show Taula -- Defined at lastHaskell.hs:175:10'. becose?

Comment: You've declared it twice - how is the compiler supposed to choose between the two?

Comment: As I define it twice? defined data type, and not only the method instance? where is the second statement?

Comment: You haven't shown it here, so I can't help you, but the compiler doesn't lie.

Comment: where reason is this?  `data Taula = Taula String [[String]] ` okey is for `deriving (show)`.

Now de poblem is other.. `Couldn't match expected type `[Char] -> [Char]'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    The function `show' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `[String] -> String' has only one
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
      `show (mostrarTaula (Taula sep lls)) ""'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
      `"" ++ show (mostrarTaula (Taula sep lls)) ""'
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what is the wanted output, but maybe you can adapt this:

```
instance Show Taula where
  show (Taula sep []) = ""
  show (Taula sep (k:lls)) = tractar sep k ++ "\n" ++ show (Taula sep lls)
```